# Propagación de argumentos en los eventos de Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, eventos, events

Estoy utilizando EventBus para notificar cambios desde un websocket y me he encontrado con que al recibir la notificación tardan en propagarse los valores de los argumentos. Me explico un poco con código.

Yo emito el evento así

```
window.eventBus.$emit("item-changed", { action: "updated", item: item });
```

En el componente donde me suscribo hago esto:

```
created() {
    window.eventBus.$on("item-changed", this.onItemUpdated);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    window.eventBus.$off("item-changed", this.onItemUpdated);
}
```

Por último, la función que maneja el evento hace esto:

```
onItemUpdated(event) {
    console.dir(event);

    if (this.action == "updated" && this.drawnIncident.Id == event.item.Objeto.Id){
        console.log("Do something");
    }            
}
```

El caso es que el console.dir muestra los datos completos, pero en el if siguiente, me dice esto:

**vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "item-changed": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of null"**

He estado investigando en español e inglés pero parece como si no le hubiera pasado a nadie. Luego de hacer pruebas me di cuenta de que si pongo un setTimeout de al menos 500 milisegundos, entonces si funciona. Pero esta solución me parece horrible.

¿Hay otra forma de solucionarlo? ¿A qué se debe esto?

Al menos me gustaría entender porqué hay este retardo en la propagación de los argumentos.